# Insufficient storage updating Android app

Tags: updates, internal-storage, chrome-for-android, insufficient-memory

Every time my Nexus S attempts to update Chrome, It displays an error stating "Insufficient storage available". According to "Manage apps" I have 412MB of internal storage available, which should be more than enough.

Searching Google turns up plenty of people with the same issue, but no definitive answer.

How do I get Chrome to update?

Comment: I know it wouldn't be the correct, but did you try to uninstall and install it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app's data size had crept up to over 100MB. Still shouldn't be a problem in my opinion, but apparently that was enough to prevent updating.

I cleared the application data "Manage apps" -> "Chrome" -> "Clear data", then was able to update Chrome successfully from Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [hardware specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_google_nexus_s-3620.php) of your phone, having 412MB of free space is equivalent to having just 2.5% of internal storage available, which seems pretty close to a low memory condition. I read somewhere (can't find the page now) that during installation you need twice as much space as what the app will finally use.

So for installing Chrome, which uses 45MB (at least on my phone), you would need 90MB free **on top** of whatever threshold your device manufacturer is using to trigger the low memory alert.