# Install/Update Apps gives "Insufficient Storage Available" error, although I already cleared the cache and other data

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, insufficient-memory, application-autoupdate

Whenever I update some app(listed below), I am getting this Error.

Insufficient Storage available. I have a Sony Xperia ZR. I have about 3.46 GB free. And the application I am trying to updates are in MBs.
I have 4.3 Jellybeans installed
I tried

1. I installed App Cache Cleaner App, and cleaned all the cache. Didn't help.
2. I deleted the app data for all those apps, whose updates weren't getting installed.
3. I connected my device to computer. I deleted all the data in Android/data folder. Didn't help
4. I uninstalled all the big apps, didn't help
5. I unistalled whatsapp(which was one app in the list), and tried to reinstall it couldn't reinstall it.

I have not rooted my phone, which I don't want to do, as I my phone is still under warranty. But I very troubled. Please help

The list of apps I am not able to get updates for

Google Chrome,
Google Search
Google Drive,
Facebook,
Youtube,
Whatsapp,
Xperia Link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insufficient storage updating Android app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33125/insufficient-storage-updating-android-app)

Comment: @sameer, no it not. I deleted all the app data, cleared all the cache still the error persists

Comment: @Anubav try clearing cache and data of Google Play store and services,  then try downloading!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and this fixed it

1. go to "/data/app-lib/APP-PATH(that has this error)/lib" and delete.
2. install/update the apk app.

If this doesn't work try going to "/data/app-lib/APP-PATH(that has this error)" and delete all the folder (but you must begin by their sub-folder then the folder itself, because you cant delete the folder of this APP-PATH directly without deleting their sub-folder first

The reason for this is that for android 4.2,+ google create a new lib folder for the apps in "/data called /data/app-lib/" and there is a symlink from "/data/data/APP-PATH/lib" to this folder which is the most culpable of this error.

I came by this knowledge here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2443267

Like I said it worked for me..

Comment: I don't have a `/data/app-lib`